# Союз "и" возле деепричастных оборотов

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Вопрос: нужно ли ставить запятую, если деепричастный оборот идет после союза "и"?

> Мы оделись **и,** взяв с собой деньги, вышли на улицу.

А если после оборота?

> Мы оделись, взяв деньги, **и** вышли на улицу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант безупречен: *Мы оделись и, взяв с собой деньги, вышли на улицу.*

Второй, после оборота, обессмысливается: *Мы оделись, взяв деньги, и вышли на улицу.* Эти "взяв деньги" стали дополнительным действием к процессу одевания.

> Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союзов «и, а, но, однако» и
> подобных, ***обычно отделяется от них запятой, за исключением случаев,
> когда деепричастный оборот нельзя оторвать от подобного союза и
> переставить в другое место предложения***. Чаще всего деепричастный
> оборот не отделяется запятой от союза «а».